# Css inline style error in Chrome: "Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive..."

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have the following html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
        <title>
        </title>
    </head>

    <style>
            .container {
                display: flex;
                display: -webkit-flex;
                justify-content: center;
            }

            .label {
                font-size: 20px;
                text-align: center;
            }

    </style>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="label">Label content.</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Despite "Content-Security-Policy" tag with 'unsafe-inline' the styles are not applied and I see the following error in Chrome:

> "Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the
> 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
> ('sha256-daGc4DKtFpvn1iqhVz5mJJ4bXSwDGTnQKoxHdrHVEhc='), or a nonce
> ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that
> 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
> fallback."

What can be done to resolve this issue?

Comment: I copied your code and pasted it into a new html document and it’s working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

This may happen because the CSP defined in the HTML differs from the one in your web server settings. In case of Apache, this is located in file '*.htaccess*'.

However, if you add a CSP with a global 'unsafe-inline' and 'unsafe-eval', there is not security at all and the CSP becomes slightly useless.

In addition, consider creating different files for HTML and CSS, and import the styles whenever you need.